# Client cookie for token in API environment

Tags: api, rest, restful-authentication

The backend for my client web application is a JSON Api.  I wanted to keep the backend generic so other devices such as mobile could reuse the same service.

Let's say each user account has a token in their profile, when they login with their username/password I send the token back.  In each subsequent request I send back the token, look it up in the database in order to find out who the user is.

As the user moves throughout the app, how/where do I store this token.  Do I store it in a cookie?  Do I drop an additional cookie in order to keep some kind of session state going?

Comment: Without any other measures, you should surely NOT use a cookie to allow access to your API. If you do, then [I can query your API from my website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), if I can make an authenticated user visit my site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not 100% RestFul.I have faced a similar situation. blogged it [here](http://sricode.blogspot.co.uk/)

The solution is, I created a singleton object to store user authentication token in the application container.Then a filter was configured to query the request and get the authentication token sent by the client. Then this token is matched against the token stored in the Singleton Session object.